# UnboundLocalError: local variable python

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to python and keep getting the error above when trying to  run the below code. Could anyone be of assistance or provide guidance?
 thanks :)

```
def feature_4():
    flower_update = input("Enter the name of the flower you wish to change the price:"
                          "Lily, Rose, Tulip, Iris, Daisy, Orchid, Dahlia, Peony")
    flower_new_price = input("Enter the updated price of the flower")
    with open('flowers.txt') as amend_price:

        for line in amend_price:
            flower_price = int(line.split(',')[1])
            flower_name = str(line.split(',')[0])

    if flower_name == flower_update:
        flower_price.append(flower_new_price)
    print("The new price of", flower_update, "is", flower_new_price)
```

Comment: Why are you opening the file in `a+` mode? This puts the file pointer at the *end* of the file, which means you never actually read any data from the file, and neither `flower_price` nor `flower_name` is defined. You never try to write to `amend_price`; just use the `'r'` mode.

Comment: @chepner I have removed a+ , how can i write to the new value to the text file?

Answer (score 1):

You ran over a common problem, you cannot read a file and modify it at the same time. at least I have no idea how to do it and there are several options you can use to achieve your goals.

When writing with "w" flag, you will erase existing file.
Thus you want to first read the file in memory, modifying it keeping it's data either in memory or in temporary files, then rewrite it.

I will skip the temporary file.

```
def feature_4(flower_file='flowers.txt'):

    flower_update = input("Enter the name of the flower you wish to change the price:"
                          "Lily, Rose, Tulip, Iris, Daisy, Orchid, Dahlia, Peony")
    flower_new_price = input("Enter the updated price of the flower")
    # here you should check that the input matches what you are expecting

    flower, price = [], []
    with open(flower_file) as amend_price:

        for line in amend_price:
            spt = line.strip().split(",")
            flower_price = int(spt[1])
            flower_name = str(spt[0])

            if flower_name == flower_update :
                price.append(flower_new_price)

            else:
                price.append(flower_price)

            flower.append(flower_name)

    with open(flower_file, "w") as f_:
        for i, v in enumerate(flower):
            f_.write("{},{}\n".format(v, str(price[i])))

    print("The new price of", flower_update, "is", flower_new_price)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have three columns within the text file. Is there a way i can do this without  it deleting the flower_quantity last column[2] when it updates?

Comment: that was not in your example... but I am sure you have an idea ^^, if you want to learn Programmation try things by yourself, for example, you can instead of using two lists use one list by fields, or use one list that store a full line. I can do the code but you will learn much more by doing and that was not your question.

Comment: I know i apologise that i did not include it in the question i did not realise. I am still struggling to update the data without it deleting flower_quantity[2] within the text file.

Comment: Would you be able to help me with this?

Comment: @MonicaMcMullan Post a different question, one question per post here in SO. Show what you have come with and add the link  to your question here as comment.